# Always active the first ul list and the first div for certain id using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs, navigation

**Problem:**

I have jQuery code that switch perfectly between tabs. However, I am wondering how it can be extended so that it also activates the first sub element of each `id`.

**Code for HTML tab navigation:**

```
<div id="navtabs">
    <div>
        <a href="#tab1" class="active btn btn-info" data-toggle="tab"><i class="icon-home"></i>Start</a>
        <a href="#tab2" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="tab"><i class="icon-book"></i>Essay</a>
        <a href="#tab3" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="tab"><i class="icon-ok-sign"></i>Criteria</a>
        <a href="#tab4" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="tab"><i class="icon-time"></i>Time</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Code for example tab:**

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">

    <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#participants" data-toggle="tab">Participants</a></li>
        <li><a href="#gradevalues" data-toggle="tab">Criteria</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="participants">Text</div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="gradevalues">Text</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

**jQuery code:**

```
$('#navtabs a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown', function () {
    $('#navtabs a[data-toggle="tab"]').attr('class','btn btn-info');
    $(this).attr('class','active btn btn-info');
})
```

**Scenario:**

When I click on the second tab (***`#tab2`***), I would like in addition to what the jQuery does now also:
(1) activate the first `li` element in `#myTab`
(2) activate the first `div` element in `#myTabContent`.

That is to say, always make sure that there is a `"class=active"` for the first `li` element and `"class=tab-pane fade in active"` for the first `div`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#navtabs a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown', function () {
    $('#navtabs a[data-toggle="tab"]').attr('class','btn btn-info');
    $(this).attr('class','active btn btn-info');

    var tabID = $(this).attr('href');
    var lis = $(tabID).find('#myTab li');//Get collection of li's
    $.each(lis, function(){
        $(this).removeClass('active'); //Remove the active class from each li
    });   
    $(tabID).find('#myTab li:eq(0)').addClass('active');//Add active class 

    //Same process for divs
    var divs = $(tabID).find('#myTabContent div');
    $.each(divs, function(){
        $(this).removeClass('in active');
    });
    $(tabID).find('#myTabContent div:eq(0)').addClass('in active');

});
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, it worked just as intended. What exactly does eq(0) do? I would appreciate a link where I can read more about this for the sake of my own learning. Again, many thanks!

Comment: for all jQuery related reading refer [jQuery.com](http://jQuery.com).
For this one particular look [here](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

Comment: I updated the answer to remove the class from all of them, but you can remove that code if it is not needed in your senerio. The "eq" pseudo selector is short for equal and the number in the parentheses represents the index number.  So it is saying "select the li whose index is 0 in the myTab container". You can read about it [here](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/). it can also be used as a function like this: `$(this).find('#myTab li').eq(0).addClass('active')`

Comment: I just realized that this does not work so well if you have more than one tab on a page. The jQuery as it is right now apply to all #myTab and all #myTabContent, but I only want it to a certain tab, say id=tab2.

Comment: I edited the answer to fix your current problem. Just grab the href value of the `<a>` element which is the id of the tab you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with and it works just fine. I just had to get which tab it was using the following:

```
$(this).attr('href')
```

And the final code looks like this:

```
$('#navtabs a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown', function () 
{
    $('#navtabs a[data-toggle="tab"]').attr('class','btn btn-info');
    $(this).attr('class','active btn btn-info');

    var lis = $($(this).attr('href')).find('#myTab li');

    $.each(lis, function(){
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    });

    $($(this).attr('href')).find('#myTab li:eq(0)').addClass('active');

    var divs = $($(this).attr('href')).find('#myTabContent div');

    $.each(divs, function(){
        $(this).removeClass('in active');
    });

    $($(this).attr('href')).find('#myTabContent div:eq(0)').addClass('in active');

});
```